# How to check that two arbitrary memory ranges are not overlapped in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

Let say I need to implement a very general utility function which has to copy one buffer to another. According to the c/c++ standard using memcpy with overlapped memory is UB on the other hand memmove is potentially slower. I would like to be able to use memcmp implementation whenever I can and switch to memmove when I have to.

```
void copy(const void* src, int src_size, void* dst, int dst_size, int count)
{
    assert(src);
    asserc(dst);
    assert(0 < count);
    assert(count < src_size);
    assert(count < dst_size);

    if (are_overlaped(src, dst, count))
        std::memove(dst, src, count);
    else
        std::memcmp(dst, src, count);
}
```

According to the c/c++ standard, it is UB to compare or subtract to arbitrary pointers. In order to write a naive implementation of are_overlaped both pointers have to points to items of the same array. So this is UB in general case

```
bool are_overlaped(const void* first, const void* second, int size)
{
    assert(first);
    asserc(second);
    assert(0 < size);

    return std::abs(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(first)
        - reinterpret_cast<const char*>(second)) < size;
}
```

So my question is how to implement are_overlaped correctly for arbitrary pointers? Or is there a standard way to check this?

PS. Example with copy is just a context for a better understanding. I want to know how to implement are_overlaped rather than use or implement copy.

Comment: There is no such thing as "c/c++" or "c/c++ standard".

Comment: If this optimization is worthwhile, `memmove` surely already does it.

Comment: pointers are just numbers; memory addresses. how would you check if two ranges of integers overlap? do the same thing.

Comment: @chris sure, except you are wrong.

Comment: You do realize that your `else` clause is doing a memory **compare** and not a memory **copy** right?  I think you meant to use `memcpy` instead of `memcmp`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont how am I wrong?

Comment: *"on the other hand memmove is potentially slower"* Sure, however, consider that checking if the memory overlaps, and then memcpying conditionally is potentially slower than memmoving.

Comment: @ChrisRollins there are many things that C (and C++) says are illegal to do with pointers that are legal to do with integers.

Comment: Cast the pointers to uintptr_t and the problem of UB is gone...

Comment: The folks who implement `memmove` know far more about their compiler and the details of the target hardware than you do. Hand-rolling your own version of `memmove` will not gain you anything.

Comment: Why provide three parameters at all? You don't use the two sizes other than for the asserts. There are just two more possibilities user can do something wrong...

Comment: glibc just aliases memcpy to memmove anyway, so I doubt the claim that memmove is slower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is legal:

```
bool inside( void const* a, void const* b, size_t count ){
  if (count==0) return false;
  if (count==1) return ptr_equal(a,b);
  return inside(a, b, count/2)||inside(a,static_cast<char const*>(b)+count/2, count-count/2 );
}
```

where `ptr_equal(a,b)` does either `!std::less<>{}(a,b)&&!std::less<>{}(b,a)` or `a==b`; I think the 2nd one is well defined, but first one is equivalent and will be well defined.

Next

```
bool overlap(void const* lhs, size_t lhs_size, void const* rhs, size_t rhs_size ){
  if (!lhs_size || !rhs_size) return false;
  auto a0 = static_cast<char const*>(lhs);
  auto b0 = static_cast<char const*>(rhs);
  return inside(a0, b0, rhs_size) || inside(a0+lhs_size-1, b0, rhs_size) || inside(b0, a0, lhs_size) || inside(b0+rhs_size-1, a0, lhs_size);
}
```

and pray your optimizer does its job on sane platforms.  Well, check.

Comment: For not overlapping blocks of memory it does 2(4) * (lhs_size + rhs_size) pointer comparisons. Yes, I agree it is a correct platform independent implementation but from the practical point of view, it is unusable.

Comment: Alternative implementation might be a "set_intersection" of both ranges, right ?

Comment: @anton you could just compare the larger elements to the end points of the smaller; that halves comparisons.  And your compiler might note that repeated equals is less/greater.  Also try with recursion replaced with a loop.

Comment: Yes, I think @Jarod42 is right and set_intersection is exactly the algorithm which describes best this solution but the only issue with standard set_intersection is that it requires a buffer of at least min(lhs_size, rhs_size). So the custom implementation of this algorithm (without copying the intersected items) should be a better solution.

Comment: @anton the real efficiency is arranging it so that the complier can optimize it to the UB version in assembly; that will require experimentation.  What happens in the abstract machine matter little *if* tue optimizer knows not to actually do it.  Which is why you should try a boring loop and repeated `==` and see what asm is produced.

Answer (score 3):

Whereas comparison on pointer is UB if those 2 pointers don't belong to same array, `std::less` can be used, something like:

```
template <typename T>
bool are_overlaped(const T* first, const T* second, int size)
{
    // `first` and `second` should be arrays of size greater or equal to `size`
    return first && second
    && (!std::less<>{}(second, first) && std::less<>{}(second, first + size)
      || !std::less<>{}(first, second) && std::less<>{}(first, second + size));


}
```

Comment: Does `std::less` not use less-than operator for pointers? Is it really well defined for pointers to separate arrays / objects?

Comment: @user2079303: It is up to the library to implement it correctly. It would probably be less-than operator on platforms where it would work. `std::set<void*>` is correct, and can be used to store pointers without requirement of being from same array .

Comment: Heh, well. There was not a bad attempt but either first + size or second + size is UB in general case. c++17 standard 8.7.4

Comment: Less is not UB, but is there a guarantee that it returns something sufficiently sensible given unrelated pointers?  I'd believe it, but I wouldn't have faith. Like, I think it could put array A inside array B (less than last, greater than min) without any element of A equal to any element of B.  All of `A` could be between `B[7]` and `B[8]`.

Comment: @AntonDyachenko -- programming is not about faith. In this regard it's about requirements, and the requirement in the language definition is that `std::less` work "correctly" for unrelated pointers. "Correctly" here primarily means consistently; there are hardware architectures (for example, segmented systems) where there is no physical meaning to "less than" for some pairs of pointers. Nevertheless, `std::less` is required to always return the same result when the same pointers are compared.

Comment: I think about this solution again and have to admit that my previous comment is not right. first + size and second + size are not UB for this function. It is correct because the preconditions to call this function is both first and second are pointers to the arbitrary memory blocks each of at least size bytes otherwise the behavior of this function is undefined and even more important it has no sense. But even though std::less<void*> specialization is defined for any pointer and establish total order the standard doesn't say that total order of pointers can be used for overlapping detection.

Comment: @akk - Adam Nevraumont is absolutely correct. Conforming standard std::less<void*> implementation doesn't have to respect "real" platform memory layout. Although standard requires that std::less(A[0]) should be less than std::less(A[last]) if last > 0 hovewer from the Yakk's example it is absolutely ok if std::less(B[7]) is less than std::less(A[0]) and std::less(A[last]) is less than std::less(B[8]) even though physically array A is not a subarray of array B that means modifying any value in range A[0]-A[last] does not observable in array B.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot about both answers. Even though @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont is perfectly correct his solution is unlikely usable. On the other hand, @Jarod42 's answer is usable but not 100% correct. Can we mix both of the solutions having enough correctness for the reasonable price? I think this is possible with a limitation of course.

```
bool may_be_overlapped(void const* lhs, size_t lhs_size_in_bytes, void const* rhs, size_t rhs_size_in_bytes)
{
    if (lhs_size_in_bytes == 0 || rhs_size_in_bytes == 0)
        return false;

    assert(lhs != nullptr);
    assert(rhs != nullptr);

    if (std::less<>(reiterpret_cast<const char*>(lhs) + lhs_size_in_bytes - 1, rhs)
        || std::less<>(reiterpret_cast<const char*>(rhs) + rhs_size_in_bytes - 1, lhs))
        return false;

    return true;
}

// wide contract
[[nodiscard]]
bool safe_copy(void* dst, size_t dst_size_in_bytes, const void* src, size_t src_size_in_bytes, size_t count_in_bytes)
{
    if (count_in_bytes == 0)
        return true;

    if (dst == nullptr || src == nullptr
     || dst_size_in_bytes < count_in_bytes
     || src_size_in_bytes < count_in_bytes)
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::memmove(dst, src, count_in_bytes);
    return true;
}

// narrow contract
void not_overlaped_copy(void* dst, size_t dst_size_in_bytes, const void* src, size_t src_size_in_bytes, size_t count_in_bytes)
{
    if (count_in_bytes == 0)
        return;

    assert(dst != nullptr);
    assert(src != nullptr);
    assert(dst_size_in_bytes >= count_in_bytes);
    assert(src_size_in_bytes >= count_in_bytes);
    assert(!may_be_overlapped(dst, count_in_bytes, src, count_in_bytes));

    std::memcpy(dst, src, count_in_bytes);
}

// narrow contract
void copy(void* dst, size_t dst_size_in_bytes, const void* src, size_t src_size_in_bytes, size_t count_in_bytes)
{
    if (count_in_bytes == 0)
        return;

    assert(dst != nullptr);
    assert(src != nullptr);
    assert(dst_size_in_bytes >= count_in_bytes);
    assert(src_size_in_bytes >= count_in_bytes);

    std::memmove(dst, src, count_in_bytes);
}
```

PS. If you do really need are_overlapped which can be used regardless of memory copy context then following is a set_intersection version of Yakk's solution:

```
bool are_overlapped(void const* lhs, size_t lhs_size_in_bytes, void const* rhs, size_t rhs_size_in_bytes)
{
    if (lhs_size_in_bytes == 0 || rhs_size_in_bytes == 0)
        return false;

    assert(lhs != nullptr);
    assert(rhs != nullptr);

    auto first1 = reiterpret_cast<const char*>(lhs);
    const auto last1 = first1 + lhs_size_in_bytes - 1;
    auto first2 = reiterpret_cast<const char*>(rhs);
    const auto last2 = first2 + rhs_size_in_bytes - 1;

    if (std::less<>(last1, first2) || std::less<>(last2, first1))
        return false;

    while (first1 <= last1 && first2 <= last2)
    {
        if (std::less<>(first1, first2))
            ++first1;
        else if (std::less<>(first2, first1))
            ++first2;
        else
            retun true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.
memmove is as efficient as memcpy, except for one check for overlap.